# Edit leading to whole new question

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828031/insert-into-mysql-database-through-php) on Stack Overflow regarding a problem with a MySQL connection.

Initially it was very obvious that the question was about a problem with a connection, but after some helpful comments and my answer, the user edited the question according to our suggestion and presented a whole new problem regarding a MySQL query in the same code.

At this point my answer appeared to be completely off-topic, so I have flagged the question for moderators intervention. What else can I do in such scenarios?

Note: A similar question has been answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93513/initial-issue-is-resolved-leading-to-second-issue-update-question-or-new-ques) but it didn't suggested actions against such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you've answered a question and it morphs into something else, roll back the change so your answer still makes sense and suggest to the asker via a comment on the question that they should ask another question instead.

I've done that for you in this case. If you can't roll the question back (because you don't have sufficient rep) flag it for moderator attention and the moderators will do it for you.

Do not try to rollback more than once though. If the OP tries to change the question again then flag for moderator attention with a custom flag and explain what's happening. Moderators have various additional tools to resolve this kind of thing.